# How to get netbios name from network computer? (Linux)

Tags: linux, bash, netbios

I want to scan my network periodically and get the Ip, mac, OS and netbios name.

So far I got everything done with a bashscript that runs nmap, but the netbiosname is still a problem.

Comment: What if nbtscan is not installed?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The program [nbtscan](http://unixwiz.net/tools/nbtscan.html) can do this.  In Ubuntu to install just use `apt-get install nbtscan`. Example usage is `nbtscan 192.168.1.0/24` on a class C network.

Answer (score 6):

more specifically,
**nbtscan -v 192.168.1.0/24**,
This will scan the  whole c class, if your node is part of the broadcast address network. (192.168.1.0)

Answer (score 1):

You could use nbtscan ( http://unixwiz.net/tools/nbtscan.html)